# Change user role in keycloke after update in existing db

Tags: keycloak

I implemented User storage SPI to use keycloak with an existing user DB, but I ran into this problem: when updating roles in my DB, roles in keycloak are not updated and all my attempts to fix this lead to errors, for example i try do disable the cache for User Federation, an error after disabling the cache:

> 21:37:46,556 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-3) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@9.0.2//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.resolveAttribute(KeycloakModelUtils.java:415)
>           at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@9.0.2//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.UserAttributeMapper.setClaim(UserAttributeMapper.java:101)
>           at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@9.0.2//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper.setClaim(AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper.java:119)
>           at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@9.0.2//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper.transformAccessToken(AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper.java:81)
>           at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@9.0.2//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.TokenManager.transformAccessToken(TokenManager.java:556)
>           at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@9.0.2//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.TokenManager.createClientAccessToken(TokenManager.java:415)

I found a workaround to solve this problem - override the getAttribute method from the UserModel interface: [workaround](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-February/017172.html) and then got this error:

> 21:42:05,659 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_41 ON PUBLIC.FED_USER_ROLE_MAPPING(ROLE_ID, USER_ID) VALUES ('3cc65575-ba9b-4248-8601-bf4a9413cb17', 'f:cbd0e1b7-c6ed-4bd2-a4eb-b47fd8201ca8:1', 1)"; SQL statement:
>   insert into FED_USER_ROLE_MAPPING (REALM_ID, STORAGE_PROVIDER_ID, ROLE_ID, USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-193]
>   21:42:05,661 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-3) Uncaught server error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>           at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
>           at org.hibernate@5.3.13.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)

if i enable the cache, then on the first request of the token I get the same error as above, and on all subsequent ones I just get the token, but the roles do not match mine from DB. What i can do with it? Thanks.

Comment: In which method from the SPI do you get the roles from the DB?

Comment: @XtremeBiker, in all UserLookupProvider methods

Comment: `roles in keycloak are not updated`, can you please elaborate on this? You mean already logged in users don't have the roles available but they get updated if they log out and in again? Or not at all?

Comment: I mean that if I change user roles in my DB, keycloak still issues a token with the roles with which it was issued for the first time
for example user has USER and ADMIN roles and keycloak issue token with this roles:
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "ROLE_USER",
      "offline_access",
      "ROLE_ADMIN",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
then i remove ROLE_ADMIN from user from my DB and keycloak still issue token with roles above

Comment: The access token gets issued more than once per user session by default. What about logging the user out and in?

Comment: @XtremeBiker, that what i see in my spring application: `[nio-9090-exec-3] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.
[nio-9090-exec-3] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Verifying access_token
[nio-9090-exec-3] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : successful authorized
[nio-9090-exec-3] a.s.a.SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticator : Completing bearer authentication. Bearer roles: [ROLE_USER, offline_access, ROLE_ADMIN, uma_authorization]` but in my database this user has only ROLE_USER.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, do you know what it can be?

Comment: @XtremeBiker, or maybe you know how i can update roles in keycloak when i updating roles in my DB?

Comment: I found a solution here: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843715/10390204).